# Phantasia4 (Java client & C server) socket timing out

Tags: java, c, sockets

There's an old codebase that uses a server in C and client in Java. The source is here: mudbytes.net/file-890

It used to work just fine years ago, but the socket is now timing out when the two try to communicate. Is there some sort of new Java policy that silently blocks communication if there is no cert or the sort?

[EDIT] Works on http://www.phantasia4.org which is a Slackware machine. But not CentOS.

Comment: Do you expect us to download the source code, compile it, try to run it and figure out what is wrong?

Comment: No, the link I provided lets you view the code online so I figured if anyone needed to see the code, they could easily do so.

Comment: I see.  Sorry, I'm not playing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some sort of new Java policy that silently blocks communication if there is no cert or the sort?

No.

There might be some such restriction on the server containers / machines / networks, but you've given us insufficient information to determine if this is a realistic possibility.

Comment: I've tried 2 different machines for the server (Slackware and CentOS) and various different computers for the client, all with the same result. The Slackware machine used to be able to run this okay, so I can only conclude something client related is happening here. And since it's a new Java version, that would be my best guess.

Comment: Well I think it is an incorrect guess. It is more likely an issue with firewalls on your client or server machines, or in the network, blocking connections on the port(s) used by the game software.

Comment: I already did a test for open ports beforehand and the client can see the server port open and running the service just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, networks tend to change over the years. There could be numerous reasons - from target changing the IP address or just falling off the face of the Internet to ISP blocking given port to aliens redirecting your traffic to a black `/dev/null`. It's all in the details you didn't give.